# Generating UML diagrams from textual representation

Tags: linux, uml

How can I generate a UML sequence diagram from a file containing a textual representation of my process, with command-line tools in Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many (many=more than 10) tools for this.
See a [complete list](http://modeling-languages.com/content/uml-tools#textual).

Answer (score 17):

Although [PlantUML](http://en.plantuml.com) is listed in the accepted answer (among many other tools) it merits more attention.

In addition to being easily wrapped into a command line tool, PlantUML also has

1. excellent documentation (check out the docs for [sequence diagrams](http://en.plantuml.com/sequence-diagram))
2. simple and powerful syntax (may compare favorably with UMLGraph)
3. styleable output
4. extensive tool integration (Emacs, Sphinx)

---

However PlantUML comes as a java archive so the following setup may be required:

1. java
2. graphviz (not required for sequence diagrams)
3. a bash wrapper

**java and graphviz** are available as packages for the major linux distros. PlantUML itself is available for Fedora and Ubuntu.

If your distribution does not provide a package, download a jar file from the main site and wrap as a bash script.

**A bash wrapper** (as follows) can be stored in a file named plantuml on your path i.e. one of the directories listed by `echo $PATH`. Don't forget to make it executable with `chmod u+x plantuml`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# from the vim syntax plugin README at aklt/plantuml-syntax on github
java -jar $HOME/path/to/plantuml.jar -tsvg $@
```

Then run `plantuml apple.uml berry.uml` and plantuml will create apple.svg berry.svg.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's what you want, but [UMLGraph](http://www.umlgraph.org/) can generate sequence diagrams using graphviz and ghostscript...

Comment: Ghostscript isn't needed.  GraphViz can directly generate PNG, SVG, and many other file types.

Comment: @Diomidis: re-reading my comment, I realize I got several things mixed up:

- GraphViz (alone) is used to generate class diagrams

- the GNU plotutils (alone) are used to generate sequence diagrams.

In some script I wrote a long time ago, I was using ghostscript to render the diagram at a high resolution. Then it was fed to ImageMagick to make the background transparent. See http://blog.julien.cayzac.name/2004/11/drawing-uml-sequence-diagrams-with-gnu.html

Answer (score 2):

If your text representation is closely similar to **[yuml](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/samples)**, you might be able to use it to produce images, e.g.

Simple Association

`[Customer]->[Billing Address]`
`<img src="http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/[Customer]->[Billing Address]"/>`
[image: Image of sample UML relationship]

Answer (score 2):

http://umlet.com/ is another solution

Answer (score 2):

Put the following source into .html file and open it in a browser:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('textarea').each(function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                    var source = $(this).html();
                    $('body').append('<img src="http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/'
                        + source + '" />');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea>
            [note: You can stick notes on diagrams too!{bg:cornsilk}],
            [Customer]<>1-orders 0..*>[Order],
            [Order]++*-*>[LineItem],
            [Order]-1>[DeliveryMethod],
            [Order]*-*>[Product],
            [Category]<->[Product],
            [DeliveryMethod]^[National],
            [DeliveryMethod]^[International]
        </textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

You should be able to see the [sample diagram](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/%5Bnote%3a%20You%20can%20stick%20notes%20on%20diagrams%20too!%7Bbg%3acornsilk%7D%5D,%5BCustomer%5D%3C%3E1-orders%200..%2a%3E%5BOrder%5D,%20%5BOrder%5D++%2a-%2a%3E%5BLineItem%5D,%20%5BOrder%5D-1%3E%5BDeliveryMethod%5D,%20%5BOrder%5D%2a-%2a%3E%5BProduct%5D,%20%5BCategory%5D%3C-%3E%5BProduct%5D,%20%5BDeliveryMethod%5D%5E%5BNational%5D,%20%5BDeliveryMethod%5D%5E%5BInternational%5D) corresponding to the source within the textarea tag. Correct the source according to the [yuml samples](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/samples) to draw your own diagram.

Answer (score -1):

Use a script to replace:

- One space with multiple spaces
- Commas with column characters, such as `|`
- Newline characters with carriage returns plus space indentation
- Dashes with multiple dashes
- Greater than and less than characters with column span characters

**References**

- [UML in Awk](http://awk.info/?doc/dsl/uml.html)
- [Transforming XMI to HTML](http://www.objectsbydesign.com/projects/xmi_to_html.html)
- [UMI SVG Modeller](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svgmodeller/)